# Push notifications not coming in Enterprise app

Tags: php, iphone, ios, push-notification

I have developed a simple app for iPad which has push notifications in it as a feature.

I created its app id and enabled the push notifications and downloaded the certificates for development as well as distribution.

I created **.pem** files for both as well.

While using development profile, everything worked fine and push notifications were working perfect.

But when I started checking it with distribution profile push notifications didn't come.

I also got the php file changed and removed sandbox from it. I checked everything but I cannot seem to find what is missing.

Do we need to do anything exclusive for Enterprise apps for enabling push notifications in them?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: Nope, I am getting connection OK

Comment: See this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: This could be caused by sending sandbox device tokens to production APNS server. See explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715921/critical-outcome-when-sending-push-notification-from-our-server/14716564#14716564).

Comment: Its resolved. It was some issue related to uploading the .pem file on the web side. They had to upload it on some other location. My web team figured out the solution. Thanks for replies folks.

Comment: @DipDhingani The same issue here . Can U plz share ,what should i need to resolve...